# Draw border with outer shadow of section in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

This one is the list item of my design. Multiple items are on the list like tableview
[image] Simply there is a rectangular item which has very thin border and outside shadow.

I have tried to convert this design into code this way. [image]

A section header, description and supervisor are the number of cell into this section.

I have tried this piece of code.

```
-(void)drawLeftBorder : (UIView *)view{

CALayer *leftBorder = [CALayer layer];
leftBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:221/255.0f green:221/255.0f blue:221/255.0f alpha:1].CGColor;
leftBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1,view.frame.size.height+1);

leftBorder.shadowColor =   [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
leftBorder.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
leftBorder.shadowOpacity = 1;
leftBorder.shadowRadius = 5;

[view.layer addSublayer:leftBorder];
}

-(void)drawRightBorder : (UIView *)view{

CALayer *rightBorder = [CALayer layer];
rightBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:221/255.0f green:221/255.0f blue:221/255.0f alpha:1].CGColor;
rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width-1,0,1,view.frame.size.height+1);

rightBorder.shadowColor =   [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
rightBorder.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
 rightBorder.shadowOpacity = 1;
rightBorder.shadowRadius = 5;


[view.layer addSublayer:rightBorder];
}



-(void)drawTopBorder : (UIView *)view{

CALayer *topBorder = [CALayer layer];
topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:221/255.0f green:221/255.0f blue:221/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,view.frame.size.width,1.0);


topBorder.shadowColor =   [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
//topBorder.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
topBorder.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
topBorder.shadowOpacity = 1;
topBorder.shadowRadius = 5;


[view.layer addSublayer:topBorder];
}
```

[image]

- Firstly line drawing is seemed okay.
- Shadow should be at outer portion of section.
- There is a break of shadow after section, and between cell
  also.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using CALayer or CAShape Layer as we can directly manipulate the section's layer to show border & shadow.

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *section = [tblView 
   dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier: @"identifier"];
    [section.layer setMasksToBounds: false];

    [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

    //Adding border to your section
    [section.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];  //Change Border Width here
    [section.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];  //Change Border Color here

    //Adding shadow to the section
    [section.layer setShadowColor: [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];  //Change Shadow Color here
    [section.layer setShadowOffset: CGSizeZero];   //Change Shadow Offset i.e shadow's displacement from section
    [section.layer setShadowRadius: 3.5];    //Change Shadow Radius i.e how far the shadow will spread
    [section.layer setShadowOpacity: 0.50];   //Change visibility of shadow here
```

Comment: This will create a shadowed border only header surrounds the section header , not   be bordered whole section (section header + cell ). please read the question carefully